# Sharing a piece of code with methods inside a class in Python

Tags: python, class

I started making a draft for one of the classes that are supposed to be used in my programm and I first wrote this piece of code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

R = 6.371e6

phi_src, theta_src = 10, 40
phi_det,theta_det = -21, 10

depth_src, depth_det = 0,0 # both on the surface

l = 0

class Trajectory:

    def __init__(self,
                 phi_src,
                 theta_src,
                 phi_det,
                 theta_det,
                 depth_src,
                 depth_det,
                 l):

        self.phi_src = phi_src
        self.theta_src = theta_src
        self.phi_det = phi_det
        self.theta_det = theta_det
        self.depth_src = depth_src
        self.depth_det = depth_det
        self.l = l
    @property

    def r(self):
        r_src = R - self.depth_src
        r_det = R - self.depth_det

        x_src = r_src * math.cos(self.phi_src) * math.cos(self.theta_src)
        y_src = r_src * math.cos(self.phi_src) * math.sin(self.theta_src)
        z_src = r_src * math.sin(self.phi_src)

        x_det = r_det * math.cos(self.phi_det) * math.cos(self.theta_det)
        y_det = r_det * math.cos(self.phi_det) * math.sin(self.theta_det)
        z_det = r_det * math.sin(self.phi_det)

        coord_src = np.array((x_src, y_src, z_src))
        coord_det = np.array((x_det, y_det, z_det))

        L = np.linalg.norm(coord_src - coord_det)

        return math.sqrt(r_src**2 + self.l * (1.0 - L - (r_src - r_det) * (r_src + r_det)/L))

    def phi(r):
        pass


trajectory = Trajectory(phi_src,theta_src,phi_det,theta_det,depth_src,depth_det,l)

print(trajectory.r)
```

But then realized that the

```
        r_src = R - self.depth_src
        r_det = R - self.depth_det

        x_src = r_src * math.cos(self.phi_src) * math.cos(self.theta_src)
        y_src = r_src * math.cos(self.phi_src) * math.sin(self.theta_src)
        z_src = r_src * math.sin(self.phi_src)

        x_det = r_det * math.cos(self.phi_det) * math.cos(self.theta_det)
        y_det = r_det * math.cos(self.phi_det) * math.sin(self.theta_det)
        z_det = r_det * math.sin(self.phi_det)

        coord_src = np.array((x_src, y_src, z_src))
        coord_det = np.array((x_det, y_det, z_det))

        L = np.linalg.norm(coord_src - coord_det)
```

part is common for all the methods of the class and hence there's no point in calculating it numerous times in every method, this piece should be shared with all the methods. 
What would be the best way to do that? Do I have to put it into the `__init__` method? I've heard it's not a good practice to make any calculations inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: If this is one-time calculation I think you could put it in `__init__` method

Comment: For me if it is like a static properties after init, you can either code it in `__init__` or create getters for them (separately).

Answer (score 0):

The common way of declaring a function in a class that does not depend on the state of the object itself is to use the `@staticmethod` decorator, followed by the function definition.  You only pass the function parameters.

If you need to use class level parameters, use `@classmethod` instead and note that you pass `cls` instead of `self` to the function (one could use any variable, so really it doesn't matter.  The point is that you are now accessing class attributes and methods instead of those of the object).

```
class Trajectory:
    c = 10  # <<< Class level property.

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 5  # <<< Object level property.

    @staticmethod
    def foo(a, b):
        return a * b

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, a, b):
        return cls.foo(a, b) * cls.c  # <<< References class level method and property.

    def baz(self, a, b):
        return self.foo(a, b) * self.c  # <<< References object level method and property.

t = Trajectory()

>>> t.foo(3, 5)
15

>>> t.bar(3, 5)
150

>>> t.baz(3, 5)
75
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, not totally sure if I get what you want, but quoting you a bit...

```
def r(self):
    r_src = R - self.depth_src
    r_det = R - self.depth_det

    ....
    L = np.linalg.norm(coord_src - coord_det)
```

This is common, you say because methods like *def r(self)* always some of these variables, like **r_src**, **L**:

```
def r(self):
    return math.sqrt(r_src**2 + self.l * (1.0 - L - (r_src - r_det) * (r_src + r_det)/L))
```

This, imho, tells me that, if you want to reuse those computations then they should be part of __init__ (or called from __init__).  But mostly, you need to set all those variables to **self**.

```
...whereever you compute them in a common location...



    self.r_src = R - self.depth_src
    self.r_det = R - self.depth_det

    ....
    self.L = np.linalg.norm(coord_src - coord_det)
```

Note that as you depend on instance variables such as **self.depth_src** in the above, this method can't be a class method, it needs to be an instance method.

Now, change your other methods to point to those precomputed attributes.

```
def r(self):

    return math.sqrt(self.r_src**2 + self.l * (1.0 - self.L   ....
```

Now, you could get fancy and only compute those attributes on demand, via **properties**.  But if you are asking a fairly basic Python question, which I think you are, then worry about optimization later and do the easiest for now.  I.e. compute them all in the __init__ or from a method called from there.

Now, there are perfectly good reasons to break them out of init, but it mostly has to do with code clarity and modularity.  If that chunk of code has some specific math/business domain meaning, then create a method that is named appropriately and call it from main.

On the other hand, some IDEs and code analyzers are better at figuring instance variables when they see them assigned in __init__ and with Python being as dynamic as it is the poor things need all the help they can get.